# How to dynamically add components to Java JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a GUI application in Java but I am having trouble in adding/updating components dynamically in JScrollPane. I have two JPanels (P1 and P2) in which P1 has a form to set parameters for application and the P2 contains some GUI components, which are updated dynamically based on the values in the P1. I need a JScrollPane on P2 to scroll, so I added JScrollPane in P2. I added both P1 and P2 to a main panel "main" and then added the main panel to a frame. But the components are not updated in P2. Can someone suggest what is the problem? I have called revalidate(), repaint() and some other methods but GUI is not updated. Below is a sample code I have written just to illustrate my problem. I need GroupLayout in my application so here I also used GroupLayout

```
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


        public class JframeExample extends JFrame {

            private final JPanel P1;
            private final JPanel P2;
            private final JPanel main;
            private final JScrollPane scrol;
            private final JButton jButton;
            private final JButton jButton2;

            public JframeExample() {
                P1 = new JPanel();
                P2 = new JPanel();
                main = new JPanel();
                jButton = new JButton("Add");
                jButton2 = new JButton("Remove");
                scrol = new JScrollPane();
                initialize();
                this.add(main);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setSize(400, 400);
                this.setVisible(true);

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                JframeExample jframeExample = new JframeExample();

            }

            private void addPressed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Add Pressed");
                scrol.add(new JButton());
                revalidate();
            }

            private void removePressed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Remove Pressed");
                scrol.removeAll();
                revalidate();
            }

            private void initialize() {
                GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(P1);
                P1.setLayout(layout);
                layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
                layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
                GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
                hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jButton).addComponent(jButton2));

                layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
                GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
                vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jButton))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jButton2));
                layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
                P2.add(scrol);
                jButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    addPressed(evt);
                });
                jButton2.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    removePressed(evt);
                });
                GroupLayout layoutMain = new GroupLayout(main);
                main.setLayout(layoutMain);
                layoutMain.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
                layoutMain.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
                layoutMain.setHorizontalGroup(layoutMain.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(P1).addComponent(P2));
                layoutMain.setVerticalGroup(layoutMain
                        .createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(P1)
                        .addComponent(P2));

            }

        }
```

Comment: Wrap `P2` inside a `JScrollPane`, add components to `P2`, call `revalidate` and `repaint` to force `P2` to update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question could be easily answered by reading through one of the many tutorials on `JScrollPane`, like [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Wrapping P2 inside JScrollPane also does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wrapping P2 inside JScrollPane also does not work.

Yes it does, because that's the way it work.  If you take the time to read through the [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), examine the examples and maybe even consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) it would provide you with the basic information you'd need to get you UI up and running.

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class JframeExample extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel P1;
    private final JPanel P2;
    private final JPanel main;
    private final JScrollPane scrol;
    private final JButton jButton;
    private final JButton jButton2;

    public JframeExample() {
        P1 = new JPanel();
        P2 = new JPanel();
        main = new JPanel();
        jButton = new JButton("Add");
        jButton2 = new JButton("Remove");
        scrol = new JScrollPane(P2);
        initialize();
        this.add(main);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JframeExample jframeExample = new JframeExample();

    }

    private void addPressed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Add Pressed");
        P2.add(new JButton());
        revalidate();
    }

    private void removePressed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Remove Pressed");
        P2.removeAll();
        revalidate();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        main.add(P1);
        main.add(scrol);
        jButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            addPressed(evt);
        });
        jButton2.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            removePressed(evt);
        });
        P1.add(jButton);
        P1.add(jButton2);
    }

}
```

Word of warning `GroupLayout` really isn't meant for hand coding, it's really designed for UI editors.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code and the output. I think something is wrong with my JVM or Operating System. I have run your code but it is not working on my computer. Very wired.

Comment: Try using `P2.revalidate()` and `P2.repaint()` instead of just `revalidate` in the `add/removePressed` methods

Comment: Not working even with P2.revalidate() and P2.repaint(). May it be platform dependent?

Comment: What OS? What JVM?

Comment: Windows 10 and Java 8 both 64 bits

Comment: Can't see it been an issue, I've had it work just find before. You might have issues with `GroupLayout` though

Comment: Yes. I saw your output. It is working perfectly fine. But at my end, it is not working.

Comment: I can't find any issues relating to Windows 10 and Swing, apart possible video card/driver related issues

Comment: Maybe I have to run my code on another machine to see what the problem is.

Comment: Your original code you've posted is not how you should be using `JScrollPane`, perhaps, if you can run, try the example I've posted

Comment: I have used the code you posted with the changes you suggested in comments but still, I can't run it on my machine.

Comment: Then from that we have to assume it's an issue with your PC/setup, because the demonstrated the code is the correct way to interact with a `JScrollPane`.  Perhaps try some of the examples from the tutorials and see if you have the same issues